# Merge or Close a Decision Element on Existing Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

See diagram below, but in a nutshell:

We have an existing flow where the final element was originally a `Decision`. Now we have business logic that needs to fall **after** that decision. When I add a (throwaway/testing) `Decision` further up the tree, as in first highlighted section, it "merges" after the 2+ decision paths so you can keep going. But the original `Decision` tree, as in second highlighted bit, doesn't have that option—it just "ends" at the end of each path.

**Is there a way to merge or close an existing `Decision` element inside a flow?** I tried switching back to the free-form view, thinking there might be a way to "force-close" the decision from that angle somehow, but no dice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no further elements after the decision Nope, so it will end. Add more elements, then press the PLUS before the end node, choose connect to element and click the element you want

Comment: Nailed it—totally missed that `Connect to Element` option. Exactly what I was hunting for, and it looks like that option is always there. ie, didn't need anything in the Nope side of that decision, so just left it empty and connected to the other branch.  Thanks so much, Simon!